# What does a folder with no .DS_Store mean?

Tags: macos, filesystems, osx-yosemite

As far as I know, every directory within OSX contains a `.DS_Store` (Desktop Service Store) file.

Recently, I had some issues with an application and noticed that it's preferences folder (in `~/Library/Preferences/<appname>`) somehow had no `.DS_Store` in it. The application issues stopped when I created a new Preferences folder with the original content. I could still browse, edit, and access the original `DS_Store`less folder.

I want to know what a folder without a `.DS_Store` file in it means to OSX, and if possible how such a thing can actually happen?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special. The `.DS_Store` file is created by the Finder to store settings for that directory, e.g. the size of the window, the display mode, and the positions of icons in the window. It is not created for directories that haven't been viewed in the Finder, or which haven't had any changes made to their display settings.

Whatever problems you had were unrelated.